# New-VM cmdlet stalls when create a new VM (works fine in vCenter)

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, powercli

Not sure were the issue is here.

I can interactively create a VM in vCenter with exactly the same settings and it creates the VM like instantly.

I just tried to do this with New-VM and it stalled at 39% and its been sitting there for like 10 mins.

Here is the command I'm running (creating this VM with the same settings in vCenter works fine).

```
$VMName = 'myVM'
$ResPool = Get-ResourcePool 'myResPool'
$Datastore = Get-Datastore 'mystore'
$Temp = Get-Template 'myTemp'
$Spec = Get-OSCustomizationSpec 'mySpec'
$Location = 'MyFolder'

New-VM -Name $VMName -Template $Temp -ResourcePool $ResPool -OSCustomizationSpec $Spec -Location $Location -Folder -Verbose
```

Edit: OK so its not stalled, but its just going super slow. Its still at 51%. When I look at the task in vCenter it says Queued For: 9 ms if that means anything.